# Javascript - Declare variables with a for loop

Tags: javascript

I'm just wondering if it's possible to declare multiple variables using a `for loop` in Javascript.

**Example:** I have 4 `<article>` elements whose Ids are `article1` `article2` `article3` and `article4`. Instead of declaring each variable independently, I'd like to do it in a loop (as they use essentially the same code and I don't want to repeat myself!).

Something like:

```
window.ready = function(){
    for (var i=1; i<=4; i++){

            var article[i] = document.getElementById("article" + i);

        }
}
```

The above returns an error with an unexpected `[`, so my syntax must be off (I'm very new to JS), but **(a) is this on the right track** and **(b) will these be global variables if I run them in a window.ready function?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot set a variable name with `[` char.  Using it, you will get an exception of javascript. You can use a List/Array to do this, try with Array class, something like:

```
window.ready = function() {

   var articles = new Array();

   for (var i=1; i<=4; i++){

      articles[i] = document.getElementById("article" + i);

   }
}
```

With Array class, you are not required to specify the lenght, but if you want, you can set it on the constructor.

```
var articles = new Array(4);
```

Another approach is use the [`push`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp) method to add elements on the array, for sample:

```
window.ready = function() {

   var articles = []; // define an empty array

   for (var i=1; i<=4; i++){

      articles.push(document.getElementById("article" + i));

   }
}
```

Comment: Ah, cool. Just so I can get the syntax right in future, is it possible to call the variable `i` in the loop (like I've tried to do with `var article[i]`)?

Comment: @Jascination, using the keyword `var` you say to javascript that you want to declare, and as `[` is a syntax error in the names of variables, you will have an exception. Because of this, I recommend you using an `Array` class, and with this, you can have as many as you want in the list. :)

Answer (score 4):

Firstly its important to note that JavaScript functions have *function scope* rather than *block scope* meaning that 'article' is not unique to your for loop. Therefore declaring `var article` within your `for` block may be misleading as to what actually happens at runtime.

To achieve what you're after the following should work:

```
window.ready = function(){
    var article = [];
    for (var i=1; i<=4; i++){

            article.push(document.getElementById("article" + i));

        }
}
```

**References**

- [Functions and function scope (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope)
- [Array push method (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a new Article Array everytime you loop through..

Create an Article Array before entering your "for" loop.

```
article = new Array(4);
    for (var i=1; i<=article.length; i++){

            article[i] = document.getElementById("article" + i);

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `eval`:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    eval( 'var article'+i+' = document.getElementById("article' + i +'");' );
}
```

This will work like normal variables and they will be visible only in a local scope. This is probably a bad practice though, so just create an array or hash table to store dynamic variables.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of that you could just grab all of the `<article>` elements:

```
var articles = document.getElementsByTagName("article");

// access them in a loop
for(var i=0; i<articles.length; i++)
{
    console.log("Hey I'm " + articles[i].id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare the array before using the array
Ex : var article = [];  // shorter version of new Array()
then write your code as it is...

Hope this will help